# Why can't a user post any comment or reply to the moderator who reviewed the flags?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, disputed-flags

I actively participate on Stack Overflow and flags low quality posts to maintain the standard of Stack Overflow, but it doesn't allow me to comment/reply to the moderator/reviewer, who reviewed the flags as decline/dispute after the changes have been made to the post that was flagged by the user. Most of posts will be deleted afterwards that moderator/reviewer reviewed as declined/disputed.

[image: Flagged posts]

The post that I flagged as offensive was deleted after I flagged it but moderator/reviewer replied me with a statement that you can read in the above snapshot.

URL of the deleted post: *[How to segment text into paragraphs using semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728635/how-to-segment-text-into-paragraphs-using-semantic)*

Why doesn't Stack Overflow allow me to comment on the reviewed flagged post by the moderators/reviewers?

Comment: You are kidding, right? What on earth is offensive on that post? And if you were able to comment what would you have said to the moderator?

Comment: @rene I get it, the OP is using java, I take offense in that, I hate managed languages...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because responding to a moderator through a comment *on the flag* would not be a good use of the moderator's time.

1. In all likelihood there would be folks who would reply just because it is easy to reply. I mean, the reply box would be right there for them to use! In some cases (maybe most cases) they would just not realize that there's a significant cost to grabbing a moderator's attention. Even the most well-intentioned person who sends an "Understood." message to the moderator has wasted the moderator's time. A single message like this does not seem like much but when you get dozens of them, it is distracting. The fact is the people who made mistakes very often like to explain themselves or at least say they are sorry. So there's that.
2. Then there are those who need to be educated about flagging. Educating them through a one-on-one discussion is not the best use of moderator time. It is better for the issue to be brought up on Meta. This way multiple people can benefit from the lesson to be learned. In some cases, the issue can even be resolved by non-moderators. Some of us have enough experience to know fairly well what the consensus is.
3. Then there are those who would pester moderators. They are probably a minority but such people can drain one's energy very quickly. Right now, they bring their grievances to Meta, which is a very good thing because people who would be likely to pester someone else in private are less likely to do so under the gaze of the community. And again the community can help set them straight. In a private dispute with a moderator, it is easy for a user to think "I'm correct but this moderator just hates me". When most responses from the community agree with the moderator, this narrative becomes more difficult to sustain. (But not impossible: some simply decide that the community is composed of sycophants.)

   I realize pesterers can currently raise a custom flag if their first flag was declined but they risk having a second flag declined. Let's not make it a less risky option for them by having a reply box.

Answer (score 19):

Once a flag has been resolved as either helpful, disputed or declined, the decision on that flag is final and we can't change it (except in some *very* specific circumstances, none of which apply to this case). If you want to dispute a response to one of your flags, feel free to either re-flag the post with a custom message and it'll be handled separately, or take it to meta on a case-by-case basis.

Since we're already here, I'd just like to echo rene's comment. I'm really not seeing what's so offensive about that question. It was deleted simply because it was a crap question. Not every crap question is offensive, unless you're saying that you're offended *by* crap questions, in which case I suggest just staying away from them in the future. Stack Overflow has no shortage of reviewers; you are not obligated to participate in review if the kind of stuff you see in the queues bothers you so much (which is perfectly understandable, this is the Internet and you *will* deal with a lot of upsetting content as a reviewer).

Comment: What is the basis for your belief that moderators are infallible and any debate is "a waste of the moderator's time"?

Comment: @augurar: When I say the decision on a flag is final, I don't mean to insinuate we're infallible - I mean we literally can't do anything to change it, and trying to get it changed by debating with us about it would be futile, even if we end up *agreeing* with you. Having said that, the "waste of time" part certainly could've been worded better considering it's directly contradicted by my very next paragraph, so I've edited my answer...

Comment: I think this doesn't rule out such a feature, but it means that if there *were* a way to discuss flags, there would also need to be a way to change the outcome of a decision.